# Apache Solr Admin on Tomcat Deployed in WebApps Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, installation, solr

I am trying to get Apache Solr to work on Redhat6 and Tomcat6 ([using these instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat)), but get this error when browsing to the admin section, `http://localhost:8080/solr-example/admin`:

> HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path
>
> type Status report
>
> message missing core name in path
>
> description The requested resource (missing core name in path) is not
>   available.

`http://localhost:8080/solr-example` loads fine, with a link to "Solr Admin."

My setup is as follows:

```
tomcat6: /etc/tomcat6
Solr: /app/solr/example
```

I have a `solr-example.xml` in `/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/`, which reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context docBase="/app/solr/example/apache-solr-3.4.0.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/app/solr/example" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

I don't see anything in the logs (`/var/log/tomcat6`) ... only entires in catalina.out are regarding the starting and stopping of tomcat6.

**My questions are:**

1.What else do I need to do to get "Solr Admin" to work under Tomcat?

2.Where are these "cores" supposed to be specified? I see an entry in /app/solr/example/solr/solr.xml ?

```
<solr persistent="false">
      adminPath: RequestHandler path to manage cores.  
        If 'null' (or absent), cores will not be manageable via request handler
      <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
        <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
      </cores>
    </solr>
```

3.How do I got about ensuring that logs are working correctly? I can't find logs that contain mention of the 404 above.

**Update in response to @quanta's comment**:

1. Downloaded former (apache-solr-3.4.0.tgz)
2. dataDir was not set, now set to: `<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:../solr/data}</dataDir>`
3. JAVA_OPTS: `/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -classpath :/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat6/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start`
4. `catalina.out` contains no indication of the above error

Comment: Which Solr package did you download: `apache-solr-3.4.0.tgz` or `apache-solr-3.4.0-src.tgz`? Did you set `dataDir` in `solrconfig.xml`? How about `JAVA_OPTS`? I suspect that there must be something in `catalina.out`.

Comment: Have you checked that the user running the Tomcat process has permissions to your solr directories?

Answer (score 1):

Your `solrconfig.xml` is located at `/app/solr/example/conf`:

```
|-- README.txt
|-- apache-solr-3.4.0.war
|-- bin
|-- conf
|   |-- admin-extra.html
|   |-- elevate.xml
|   |-- mapping-FoldToASCII.txt
|   |-- mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt
|   |-- protwords.txt
|   |-- schema.xml
|   |-- scripts.conf
|   |-- solrconfig.xml
|   |-- spellings.txt
|   |-- stopwords.txt
|   |-- stopwords_en.txt
|   |-- synonyms.txt
|   |-- velocity
|   `-- xslt
|-- data
|   |-- index
|   `-- spellchecker
`-- solr.xml
```

If you set the `dataDir` to `../solr/data`, it means that this directory... doesn't exist. So, change it to the obsolute path `/app/solr/example/data` and try again.

Comment: I tried that, and still getting `missing core in path name` at http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/

Comment: `localhost:8080/solr/admin` or `localhost:8080/solr-example/admin`. Please describe in detail all steps you did.